# Cannot read property 'parentNode', AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I'm trying to fill a datatable:

```
let cb = this.API.all('cardboard_querys/' + $stateParams.id);

cb.customGET().then((response) => {
    let data = response.data.cardboard_querys;

    console.log('data',data)

    this.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withOption('data', data)
        .withOption('responsive', true)
        .withBootstrap()
        .withDOM('<"html5buttons"B>lfTtipr')


    this.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID').withOption('defaultContent', ''),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('request_type').withTitle('Tipo').withOption('defaultContent', ''),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('request_number').withTitle('request_number').withOption('defaultContent', ''),
    ]
});
```

In my view:

```
<table datatable="" class="table table-responsive table-striped"
       dt-options="vm.dtOptions" dt-columns="vm.dtColumns">
</table>
```

But I get the following errors:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined
>     at _fnSortFlatten (final-b72999cec5.js:83355)
>     at _fnSortingClasses (final-b72999cec5.js:83693)
>     at loadedInit (final-b72999cec5.js:78692)
>     at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (final-b72999cec5.js:78790)
>     at Function.each (final-b72999cec5.js:362)
>     at jQuery.fn.init.each (final-b72999cec5.js:157)
>     at jQuery.fn.init.DataTable [as dataTable] (final-b72999cec5.js:78352)
>     at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.DataTable (final-b72999cec5.js:92552)
>     at Object.renderDataTable (final-b72999cec5.js:108237)
>     at Object.hideLoadingAndRenderDataTable (final-b72999cec5.js:108253)
>
>  TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
>     at _Api.<anonymous> (final-b72999cec5.js:86750)
>     at _Api.iterator (final-b72999cec5.js:84495)
>     at _Api.<anonymous> (final-b72999cec5.js:86749)
>     at _Api.destroy (final-b72999cec5.js:84663)
>     at jQuery.fn.init.DataTable.fnDestroy (final-b72999cec5.js:77895)
>     at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (final-b72999cec5.js:78406)
>     at Function.each (final-b72999cec5.js:362)
>     at jQuery.fn.init.each (final-b72999cec5.js:157)
>     at jQuery.fn.init.DataTable [as dataTable] (final-b72999cec5.js:78352)
>     at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.DataTable (final-b72999cec5.js:92552)
> ```

192/5000

I really do not know what I can be doing wrong, in another project it works perfectly. Neither am I very skillful to be said in angular. I have searched a lot but I still can not find the solution.

What am I doing wrong?? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know much about datatables in angularjs, but looks like something is missing in your first attribute: `datatable=""` .  See the example here: https://www.js-tutorials.com/angularjs-tutorial/angular-datatables-example-multiple-datatables-single-page/

Comment: What version of angular-datatables does the code use?